# java JDBC Driver connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Whenever i am executing my code of creating connection:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo");
```

I am getting this exception,

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client
>   does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider
>   upgrading MySQL client

What is the solution of this problem?

Comment: Download a newer version of mysql connector/j.

Comment: *"What is the solution of this problem?"* Follow the recommendation in the error message: **consider upgrading MySQL client**, aka the JDBC driver. You did *read* the error message, right?

Answer (score 0):

Download the newest version of JDBC. I had the same problem. I downloaded another version and it worked!!

Comment: You can't  download JDBC. It s part of the JRE. He needs to  download the latest version of the MySQL driver.

Comment: part of JRE?ah. But I had to download it manually from mySQL website.I m talking about mysql-connector-java.jar

Comment: JDBC is an API that is part of Java itself (packages `java.sql` and `javax.sql`), what the OP needs to download is a JDBC driver for MySQL (aka MySQL Connector/J). This driver **implements** the JDBC API.